# Which bean can I use as a alternative one of http-outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I am changing spring-integration 3.x to 4.x.
And I should change every xml configuration to the java file.

But, I can't find the bean that can be replaced in place of the followings.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather={city}"
                           http-method="GET"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           request-factory="requestFactory"
                           request-channel="requestChannel"
                           reply-channel="replyChannel">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="city" expression="payload"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<bean id="requestFactory"
      class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="readTimeout"    value="5000"/>
</bean>
```

I tried using the HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler for it.

```
@Bean
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpGateway() {
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler gateway 
        = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(gitlabUri);
        gateway.setOutputChannel(requestChannel());
        return gateway;
    }
```

But it doesn't have the request channel as a parameter.

Help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML parser creates 2 beans for outbound endpoints; a `Consumer` bean (event-driven or pollable, depending on the input channel type) and the message handler, which is injected into the consumer. A `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` is used to generate the appropriate consumer.

So, you can either wire up the 2 beans yourself, or, use a `@ServiceActivator` annotation and the framework will take care of creating the the consumer for you...

```
@ServiceActivator(input-channel="toHttp")
@Bean
HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpGateway() {
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler gateway 
        = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(gitlabUri);
    gateway.setOutputChannel(requestChannel());
    return gateway;
}
```

See [the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15193) for more details. It uses the HTTP endpoint as an example.